# Gravar dados de comunicação da pessoa

Tags: php

Estou tentando gravar em meu `BD` dados de comunicação de uma pessoa e não estou conseguindo resolver, os dados dessa comunicação são `Email`, `Telefone Empresa`, `Celular Empresa` e `Ramal`, cada um desses são Tipos cadastrados em uma tabela chamada `cadTipoComunicacao` e posteriormente tento gravar esses dados em uma tabela chama cadComunicacao.

Tenho as informações disponíveis:

```
    // TIPOS DE COMUNICAÇÃO
    $IdTipoRamal = 1;   
    $IdTipoTe = 3;
    $IdTipoCe = 4;
    $IdTipoEmail = 6;

    // INFORMAÇÃO
    $Ramal = 1820;  
    $TelEmpresa = '(44) 3733-8810';
    $CelEmpresa = '(44) 99898-8585';    
    $Email = 'teste.emmpresa@empresa.com.br';
```

E seguinte estrutura para o `agrupar` as informações:

```
    $Registros = array (
      array($IdTipoRamal,$Ramal),     
      array($IdTipoTe, $TelEmpresa),
      array($IdTipoCe, $CelEmpresa),
      array($IdTipoEmail, $Email)
    );
```

O que estou fazendo para exibir as informações:

```
for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {   
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {
    echo "<li>".$Registros[$row][$col]."</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

A saída desse código é isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código de Insert da tentativa que fiz é esse:

```
// DADOS DA COMUNICAÇÃO
$Registros = array (
  array($IdTipoRamal,$Ramal),     
  array($IdTipoTe, $TelEmpresa),
  array($IdTipoCe, $CelEmpresa),
  array($IdTipoEmail, $Email)
);

// INSERIR  
for ($row = 0; $row < 4; $row++) {     
  // echo "<ul>";
  for ($col = 0; $col < 2; $col++) {
    // echo "<li>".$Registros[$row][$col]."</li>";

    $crud = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO cadComunicacao ( IdPessoa, IdTipo, Informacao ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $crud->bindParam(1, $IdPessoa , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(2, $IdTipo , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(3, $Informacao , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $retorno = $crud->execute();           

  }
  // echo "</ul>";
}
```

O que não estou conseguindo fazer é percorrer o loop e gravar IdTipo e Informacao, sendo que na imagem o IdTipo é o primeiro valor e a Informacao é a segunda.

Não posso gravar tudo no campo `Informacao`, preciso percorrer o loop e ir gravando a `IdPessoa`, `IdTipo` e a `Informacao, que no caso acima podem ser várias linhas para IdTipo e Informação.

A tabela cadComunicacao, onde estou tentando gravar as informações tem essa estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer inserir os dados em 2 tabelas certo? Mas sendo que em 1 tabela os dados serão divididos em vários campos e na outra todos os dados serão inseridos em um único campo? Se for isso, tu pode juntar tudo numa string e inserir na 2 tabela.

Comment: Olá @Leonardo, preciso inserir somente na tabela cadComunicacao.

Comment: Esse teu campo "Informacao" é um varchar de 80. Aumenta ele e concatena teus campos e insere nele.

Exemplo: 

$informacao = "$variavel1 . $variavel2 . $variavel3 . $variavel4";

Comment: Olá @Everson, sim, tem que ser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que fez uma grande confusão no modo como você puxa os dados para inserir na tabela, pode simplificar usando `foreach`, veja como:

```
$IdPessoa = 1;
$IdTipoRamal = 1;   
$IdTipoTe = 3;
$IdTipoCe = 4;
$IdTipoEmail = 6;
$Ramal = 1820;  
$TelEmpresa = '(44) 3733-8810';
$CelEmpresa = '(44) 99898-8585';    
$Email = 'teste.emmpresa@empresa.com.br';
$Registros = array (
    array($IdTipoRamal,$Ramal),     
    array($IdTipoTe, $TelEmpresa),
    array($IdTipoCe, $CelEmpresa),
    array($IdTipoEmail, $Email)
);
foreach($Registros as &$value){
    $crud = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO cadComunicacao ( IdPessoa, IdTipo, Informacao ) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
    $crud->bindParam(1, $IdPessoa , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(2, $value[0] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam(3, $value[1] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $retorno = $crud->execute(); 
}
```

Se quiser tentar simplificar, fazer apenas um execute em vez de vários, pode tentar fazer assim (Apesar de **eu** preferir a primeira forma):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO cadComunicacao ( IdPessoa, IdTipo, Informacao ) VALUES ";
foreach($Registros as &$value){
    $sql .= "(?, ?, ?),";
}
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
$crud = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$i = 1;
foreach($Registros as &$value){
    $crud->bindParam($i++, $IdPessoa , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam($i++, $value[0] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $crud->bindParam($i++, $value[1] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$retorno = $crud->execute();
```

## TL;DR:

Recomendo que faça esse procedimento dentro de um `try... catch`, caso houver algum erro, fica mais fácil de tratar, mais ou menos assim:

```
try {
    $crud = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $i = 1;
    foreach($Registros as &$value){
        $crud->bindParam($i++, $IdPessoa , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $crud->bindParam($i++, $value[0] , PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $crud->bindParam($i++, $value[1] , PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
    $retorno = $crud->execute();                    
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die($e);
}
```

---

Uma ultima, mas não menos importante dica

Dentro do `try catch` mostrei um modo de exibir os erros na tela, mas isso não deve ser feito em um ambiente de produção.... tome cuidado porque isso expõe um pouco a sua estrutura, e também não é nada elegante mostrar um erro desses aos clientes

O que pode ser feito é criar uma função que logue esses erros, seja em um arquivo `.txt`, ou no banco de dados por exemplo.

Como eu costumo fazer:

```
function create_log( $filename, $string ) {
    date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
    file_put_contents( $filename, date( 'r' )." ".$string.PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND );
}
```

E dentro do `try catch`:

```
try {
  // Código      
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  http_response_code(500);
  // Removo todas informações que não devem ser salvas no log
  unset($_POST["senha"]);
  create_log( "logs/db_errors.log", "Informação adicional.PHP_EOL.json_encode($_POST).PHP_EOL."Exception: ".$e );
  // Com uma transaction ativa, comando desfaz tudo que foi feito no banco de dados
  // $db->rollBack();
  // Com uma transaction ativa, comando "salva" tudo que foi feito no banco de dados antes do erro que gerou a exception 
  // $db->commit();
  // Utilize a que melhor se adeque no seu caso
  die(); // Retorno vazio
}
```

Comment: Olá @MarceloBoni, obrigado pela paciência em montar tantas opções para o meu caso, ficou perfeito, simples e esclarecedor.

Comment: Bom, só espero que tenha funcionado :)

Comment: Olá @MarceloBoni, funcionou perfeitamente.